# How to install multiple WebAddresses conditionally?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have a website that I am installing for one of our internal products, and would like to know if there is a way to set up multiple `<WebAddress/>` blocks to be conditionally installed along with this one website?

Consider my basic website authoring below:

```
<Component
    Id="WebsiteComp"
    Directory="INSTALLDIR"
    Guid="{702AF20D-F9F3-45A1-B966-890855904591}"
    KeyPath="yes">

  <iis:WebAppPool
      Id="AppPool"
      Name="OurSite"
      ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated"
      ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>

  <iis:WebSite
      Id="Website"
      Description="[WEBSITENAME]"
      Directory="INSTALLDIR">

    <iis:WebApplication
        Id="WebApp"
        Name="[WEBSITENAME]"
        WebAppPool="AppPool"/>

    <!-- if ENV = "DEV" -->
    <iis:WebAddress
        Id="DevHostHeader"
        Header="dev.product.company.com"
        Port="80"/>

    <!-- if ENV = "QA" -->
    <iis:WebAddress
        Id="QaHostHeader"
        Header="qa.product.company.com"
        Port="80"/>

    <iis:WebAddress
        Id="QaHostHeader"
        Header="product.qa1.company.com"
        Port="80"/>

    <!-- if ENV = "PROD" -->
    <iis:WebAddress
        Id="ProdHostHeader"
        Header="prod.product.com"
        Port="80"/>
  </iis:WebSite>
</Component>
```

`<Component/>` is the most specific element that a condition can applied to. But in order to specify the condition there I have to duplicate all my web site auhtoring for each environment, correct?

Is there a way to author one version of the `<WebAppPool/>`, `<WebSite/>`, and `<WebApplication/>` and then have different versions and quantities (like QA in the above example) of `<WebAddress/>` inserted/chosen based on the condition of a propertie's value?

I really don't want to get into making multiple versions of the installer for a specific environment.

Thank you,
Zachary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to do it without code duplication... pre-processor to the rescue!

Here's a simplified look at my "web services" directory:

```
ProductName.WebService.wxs
ProductName.DEV.WebAddress.wxi
ProductName.PROD.WebAddress.wx
ProductName.QA1.WebAddress.wxi
```

`ProductName.WebService.wxs` is as follows:

```
<Wix
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">

  <Fragment>
    <iis:WebDirProperties .../>

    <?foreach EnvID in DEV;PROD;QA1 ?>
    <?define FullEnvID = "ProductName.$(var.EnvID)" ?>

      <?if     $(var.EnvID) = "DEV" ?>
        <?define CompGUID   = "{DFEAC94A-590E-4E92-9206-E574ABDDBB29}" ?>
      <?elseif $(var.EnvID) = "PROD" ?>
        <?define CompGUID   = "{FEE4FBB1-9894-48F4-8DDC-9FC83F8AD778}" ?>
      <?elseif $(var.EnvID) = "QA1" ?>
        <?define CompGUID   = "{EED17AF6-BF99-4B34-821D-6A8487292111}" ?>
      <?endif ?>

      <Component
          Id="$(var.FullEnvID).WebSvc"
          Directory="INSTALLDIR"
          Guid="$(var.CompGUID)"
          KeyPath="yes">
        <Condition><![CDATA[ENV="$(var.EnvID)"]]></Condition>

        <iis:WebAppPool
            Id="$(var.FullEnvID).WebAppPool"
            Name="[WEBSITENAME]"
            ManagedPipelineMode="Integrated"
            ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0"/>

        <iis:WebSite
            Id="$(var.FullEnvID).Website"
            Description="[WEBSITENAME]"
            Directory="INSTALLDIR">

          <iis:WebApplication
              Id="$(var.FullEnvID).WebApplication"
              Name="[WEBSITENAME]"
              WebAppPool="$(var.FullEnvID).WebAppPool"/>

          <?include $(var.FullEnvID).WebAddress.wxi ?>
        </iis:WebSite>
      </Component>

      <?undef CompGUID ?>
      <?undef FullEnvID ?>
    <?endforeach ?>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

1. `<Condition><![CDATA[ENV="$(var.EnvID)"]]></Condition>` determines which web site component is installed
2. `<?include $(var.FullEnvID).WebAddress.wxi ?>` slips in just the `<iis:WebAddress/>` sections as the  loop iterates.

Here's what `ProductName.DEV.WebAddress.wxi` looks like:

```
<Include
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
    xmlns:iis="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/IIsExtension">
  <iis:WebAddress
      Id="dev.product.company.com"
      Header="dev.product.company.com"
      Port="80"/>

  <iis:WebAddress
      Id="product.dev.company.com"
      Header="product.dev.company.com"
      Port="80"/>
</Include>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can approach the problem in a different way.

You can have a single [WebAddress](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/iis_xsd_webaddress.htm) element, and the `Header` attribute will take the value of the property. Like this:

```
<iis:WebAddress Id="HostHeader" Header="[HOSTHEADER]" Port="80"/>
```

Now, based on the condition (production, DEV, QA) you set the property to the required value, for instance, `qa.product.company.com` for QA. Thus, you'll conditionally install the host header you need, and will keep a single WebAddress entry in the sources. Note, that `Port` attribute can accept the property values as well.

Comment: Hi Yan, Thank you for your response. I'm not sure if you saw it in the example authoring above, but one of the issues for the QA environment is that the web site needs to respond to no less than three different host values: something like product.qa.company.com, qa.product.company.com, and product.subproduct.company.com. So, I'll need to be able to conditionally install 3 addresses in QA, maybe 2 in DEV, and 3 or more again in PROD. I've played around a bit since posting this question and it looks like I'll have to bite the bullet and duplicate code. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Zachary Young, Ah, I see now. This is indeed in your question sample, I simply didn't pay enough attention, sorry... Hmm, in this case I think you'll have to duplicate `<WebSite>` elements (and thus, Components) for each of your environment (dev, qa, prod), and each of these websites will contain necessary `WebAddress` elements. Basically, that's the way you mentioned yourself - I don't see other option here...